# How can I find the number of support vectors in an SVM, depending on kernel?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

[Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/slides/Kernels_SVM2_04_12_2011-ann.pdf) on slide 3 I see the claim that for linearly separable cases the number of support vectors will be d+1, where d is the dimension we are working on.

What if my data is not linearly separable and I use polynomial or RBF kernel?

Is there a way to know what will be the number of support vectors?

Comment: No, there is not.